# RadioGroup : I use onCheckedChangeListener method. How can I make it possible that if user select the already selected Button, the method still runs?

Tags: android

I use onCheckedChangeListener to return the result back to MainActivity and finish the current activity. But if user decides to use the default selected value, he'd like to re-click the radiobutton to save result. How can I do that?
Thanks

Edit:
In short, how do I know if a user selects an already selected radiobutton?

Comment: I got lost in this part `But if user decides to use the default selected value, he'd like to re-click the radiobutton to save result`. Can you explain a bit more

Answer (score 0):

If user selects the selected value then nothing changes and this method won't get called but you can check whenever you want that which radio button in a radio group is selected it should work.
If you want to check whether user has selected a different option just compare the current selection with default selection.

Comment: Yup I am doing that, but user won't be able to return to MainActivity. He has to select a wrong option, which automatically returns him back, then re-select the right option. (I'm using sharedPreferences to save the choice he last selected)

Comment: Can you give a snapshot of the activity with the exact requirement.